# Should I escape "double quotation marks" in SQL statament in Phpadmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I am ready to run this SQL statement in phpAdmin/SQL:

```
update wp_postmeta set meta_value =
replace(meta_value,'s:14:"_product_block";s:1:"0"','s:14:"_product_block";s:5:"26938"');
```

**Should I escape the "quotation marks"?**

I mean the double quotation marks: **"**

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try this by yourself?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I tried but it is not working. I doesn't find the string even when I am 100% sure that the text is there. I tried with text with no double quotation marks and it works fine. Then I assume that the problem are the double quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed to uppercase and get it working. Just in case someone have the same issue.

from this `update wp_postmeta set meta_value`
to this `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value`